# Ember CLI cannot resolve nested partials

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a simple partial used in my `application.hbs` file: `{{partial "atoms/header_message"}}` The path for the partial is `templates/atoms/header_message`

According to the [CLI Documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#layout-within-app-directory):

> The templates are named the same as their filename, minus the extension (i.e. `templates/foo/bar.hbs` -> `foo/bar`).

So pod structure or not, it should simply resolve the path. However I get this fancy error:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find partial with name "atoms/header_message"

Am I naming things wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dashes instead of underscores :)

Answer (score -1):

Your partials need to be reference with periods instead of slashes.

`{{partial 'atoms.header_message'}}`

Comment: That doesnt work. I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: templateNames are not allowed to contain periods: _atoms.header_message`